# Agda rewrite does not change goal in _*_ commutativity proof

Tags: proof, agda, commutativity

**SOLVED**: I have a solution after following **white-wolf**'s advice. If you are interested in my solution feel free to message me.

---

I am trying to write a proof in Agda for commutativity for multiplication:

```
lem3 : (x y : ℕ) → (x * y) ≡ (y * x)
lem3 0 y rewrite pr3a y = refl
lem3 (suc x) y rewrite lem3 x y | pr3b x y = refl
```

where we have:

```
pr3a : (x : ℕ) → (x * 0) ≡ 0
pr3a 0 = refl
pr3a (suc x) with (x * 0) | pr3a x
... | .0 | refl = refl

pr3b : (x y : ℕ) →  y + y * x ≡ y * suc x
pr3b 0 0 = refl
pr3b 0 (suc y) rewrite pr3b 0 y = refl
pr3b (suc x) y = {!!}
```

I am having trouble filing this final goal. The expected type is `y + y * suc x ≡ y * suc (suc x)`, and I had expected that using `rewrite` would give me `y * suc (suc x) ≡ y * suc (suc x)` as a goal. However:

```
pr3b (suc x) y rewrite pr3b x y = {!!}
```

expects the same goal as before: `y + y * suc x ≡ y * suc (suc x)`.

It is my understanding that `rewrite` would effectively substitute the RHS into the LHS for x = x, giving `y * suc x ≡ y * suc x`, and then use x = suc x to give `y * suc (suc x) ≡ y * suc (suc x)`. Am I mis-understanding how `rewrite` works or have I made some other error?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your goal is `y + y * suc x ≡ y * suc (suc x)`. Your induction hypothesis is `y + y * x ≡ y * suc x`. I can check that by putting `pr3b x y` inside the goal and typing C-c C-.

```
Goal: y + y * suc x ≡ y * suc (suc x)
Have: y + y * x ≡ y * suc x
```

This means that with a rewrite you should be able to replace `y * suc x` with `y * x`. However, you see that the two sides are switched, so you have to rewrite with symmetry like so

```
pr3b : (x y : ℕ) →  y + y * x ≡ y * suc x
pr3b 0 0 = refl
pr3b 0 (suc y) rewrite pr3b 0 y = refl
pr3b (suc x) y rewrite sym $ pr3b x y = {!!}
```

This promotes the goal to `y + (y + y * x) ≡ y * suc (suc x)`. This particular proof requires associativity and commutativity of addition to be completed.

Edit

I think you should try to prove this by induction on `y` instead of `x`.